# Не установить mysql 5.6

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

До этого был установлен 5.5 вот эти способом https://askubuntu.com/a/811314

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6
[sudo] пароль для duke: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Зависит: initscripts но он не может быть установлен
                    Зависит: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) но он не может быть установлен или
                                    file-rc (>= 0.8.16) но он не может быть установлен
                    Рекомендует: libhtml-template-perl но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

ОС Ubuntu 16.10

---

Вот, что я уже пробовал:

```
$ sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf  
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get clean 
$ sudo apt-get autoclean 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

А также пробовал лечить через synaptic

Answer (score 2):

Удалите кеш пакетов:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Удалите осиротевшие пакеты:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Обновите список пакетов:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Исправьте зависимости:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Обычно этого достаточно.
Если вы запутались с зависимостями, поможет интеллектуальное обновление системы:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Если установка была прервана, то следует переустановить пакет

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall имя_пакета
```

Сначала сделает бэкап

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p --all-databases > dump.sql
```

После установки

```
mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
```

Сделаете очистку системы

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Update::
1)
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
2)
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6

sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6

Comment: Не помогает. К тому же, я не знаю, какой именно пакет повреждён

Comment: Знаете. initscripts  sysv-rc

Comment: Они даже не установлены